# Citing websites with LyX and Citavi

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx

I'm using Citavi to maintain my literature sources, then export them to a `.bib` file and have LyX generate the bibliography from that.

However, when citing websites, Citavi does not create all necessary values in the .bib file, or names them differently than most bibliography styles expect.

**The two biggest problems are:**

1. Citavi saves the URL of the website as `url = {http://www.example.org}`, but some (many? most?) bibliography styles only recognize it when the entry is called `howpublished = {http://www.example.org}`.
2. Citavi does not add any *"Last accessed on..."* date at all. It seems to be a convention to write this in a note, like `note = {Last accessed on December 27, 2016}`

**This is an example of what Citavi creates:**

`@misc{Huynh.,
    author = {Huynh, Trung Dong and Moreau, Luc},
    title = {ProvStore: a public provenance repository},
    url = {https://provenance.ecs.soton.ac.uk/store/},
    urldate = {2016-12-27}
}`

**And this is how it should be:**

`@misc{Huynh.,
    author = {Huynh, Trung Dong and Moreau, Luc},
    title = {ProvStore: a public provenance repository},
    howpublished = {https://provenance.ecs.soton.ac.uk/store/},
    note = {Last accessed on December 27, 2016}
}`

I'm looking for a way to make Citavi export a correct .bib file that will work well in LyX with **Citation Style: Default (numerical)** and **Bibliography Style: unsrt**.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it partially; not finished yet, but I'm writing it down, so I won't forget it.

---

## In Citavi:

1. Go to **File > Export > Export**, select which titles you want to export, and click **Next**.
2. Select **BibTeX** and click **Next**.
3. Choose the desired output path/file, then click **Edit BibTeX export definition...**
4. Leave everything unchanged in the first window, click **Next**.
5. From the dropdown at the top, select **Internet document**
6. Next to **Online address**, remove `url` and type `howpublished` instead.
7. Next to **Access date**, remove `urldate` and type `note` instead.
8. Just click **Next**/**Ok**/**Finish** on everything that follows. *(It will ask you whether you want to save your BibTeX export settings, and later also your general export settings. Do that if you like.)*

Now the entries in the .bib file will be formatted almost as desired. (I still have to find a way to make it look *exactly* like I wrote in the question.)

## In LyX:

[image]

[image]

## Result:

[image]

---

As you can see, it's still lacking some text like *"Available online at..."* and *"Last checked on..."*, and the date is not formatted nicely. I'll work on that and write an update as soon as I've found a good way.